# EntityFrameWork DataFirst and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project utilizing MVC4 and EF Data First in VS2012. The table has a primary key which does not have "id" in the field name so EF does not understand it should use it as the primary key. After EF generates the code I add the following annotations and using statements.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class Game
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int GameNumber { get; set; }
```

If I base my models from the generate code the custom changes I make will be discard if I update the database models. How can I keep my custom changes and update the database EF data model.

Thanks

Comment: Just mark it as PK in the edmx diagram. But why didn't EF recognize it as primary key when the edmx was first built? It should have, if it was defined as PK in the database.

Comment: I see you got an answer, but you can (and should) do these things in the edmx. There's really no need for buddy classes here. I still wonder why you don't seem to have a PK in the store model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `MetadataTypeAttribute` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx)) to define a metadata class on a partial implementation of your entity class, then decorate the properties in that metadata class.

Note that the decorated partial class implementation should exist in a file other than the autogenerated file so as to persist refreshing from DB.

(question: if your model is DB first, why doesn't it know what the PK is for the `Game` table?  Whether or not the property has `Id` at the end doesn't matter when it's reading the table schema to generate the model...)

```
[MetadataType("GameMetadata")]
public partial class Game
{
    public class GameMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int GameNumber; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, found what I was looking for.